# Member list with Demographic Data - is there a module or how do I build a View?

Tags: views, users

I want to be able to do a Member Directory page that when clicked, displays a sortable view of Users, including First name, Last name, etc.

Is there a module for this or how do I build a View?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a view of type user will allow you to extracts necessary user and profile fields to list in you view.

- Go to `admin/build/views`then click on`Add`.
- Define view name, description, tag and select view type as `user`.
- Add you display type `page` or `block`
- Alter/Override views settings
- Add fields, the list can expand
- Select view's format style as table, and configure this style for fields to sortable.

For demography point of view there are few date specific fields like created, last login.

This list can grow depending on module extending user entity e.g. profile